# Sacar cadena de texto PHP - substr

Tags: php, substr

Si la nomenclatura de substr es:

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

¿Cómo le digo que tiene que cogerme la cadena de inicio hasta que encuentre un "." de la extensión?

Es decir: si tenemos "cadena.php", extraer únicamente "cadena".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo combinando `substr` con  `strpos`, o explotando con `.`

```
<?php

$cadena='archivo.php';

// opcion 1

$cadena_cortada = substr($cadena,0, strpos($cadena,'.'));

print_r('<br>opción 1 "'.$cadena_cortada.'"');


// opcion 2

$cadena_arr = explode('.',$cadena);

print_r('<br>opción 2 "'.$cadena_arr[0].'"');
```

La opción 1 se acerca más a lo que tratas de hacer, pero si le pasas un carácter que no está en la cadena, el resultado será un string vacío.

Con la opción de `explode` siempre te devolverá algo.

Ahora, si quisieras que te devolviera la cadena desde el inicio hasta la última ocurrencia de un caracter, ahí hay que empezar a meter comprobaciones, por ejemplo usando  `strpos` para verificar que el carácter existe, o bien explotando y verificando el largo del array resultante. Digamos por ejemplo que tu cadena es `archivo.con.datos.php` y quieres sólo `archivo.con.datos`

```
$cadena_arr2 = explode('.','archivo.con.datos.php');
$elementos = count($cadena_arr2);
print_r('<br>La cadena explotada tiene '.$elementos.' elementos');
if($elementos>1) {
    // quitamos el último elemento  
    array_pop($cadena_arr2);    
}
print_r('<br>opción 3 "'.implode('.',$cadena_arr2).'"');
```

Comment: Para el caso donde el nombre del archivo sea `archivo.con.datos.php`, también podrías usar [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php) y `substr`

Comment: Claro. También podrías usar strpos sobre la cadena invertida. Hay mil maneras y, como todo en PHP, entre medio hay funciones que son inconsistentes en el orden de los parámetros :D

Answer (score 1):

`substr()` sólo te permite empezar desde la posición indicada y continuar el número de caracteres que le indiques.

Utiliza [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

```
$string = "cadena.php";
$resultado = explode(".", $string);
```

Con `substr()` no puedes indicarle el carácter sobre el que quieres terminar, para eso sirve `explode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [strtok()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtok.php), la cual de divide una cadena en cadenas más pequeños y te lo **devuelve como una cadena (string)**.

```
echo strtok('cadena.php', '.'); // cadena
```